# How to order a nested Linq object via orderBy

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, nested, nested-object

so I wanted to order a nested object,
this "someObject" object has "Values" object as in its inside.
How do I order this nested object via orderBy.

```
mySendendId=11

someObject=
Id=1
Values===
          Id=10     numeric =20     text=null
          Id=11     numeric =1.4    text=null
          Id=12     numeric =32     text=null
          Id=13     numeric=null    text=”abcde”

Id=2
Values===
          Id=10     numeric =21     text=null
          Id=11     numeric =1.2    text=null
          Id=12     numeric =33     text=null
          Id=13     numeric=null    text=”bcde”

Id=3
Values===
          Id=10     numeric =22     text=null
          Id=11     numeric =1.3    text=null
          Id=12     numeric =34     text=null
          Id=13     numeric=null    text=”cde”
```

someObject =1,2,3

```
orderedObject = someObject.orderBy(a=>a.Values.(b=>b.numeric).Where(b=>b.Id= =mySendendId))
```

orderedObject =2,3,1

I already tried

```
orderedObject= someObject.OrderBy(a => a.Id).Where(a => a.Values.OrderBy(b => b.Numeric).Any(b => b.Id == mySenedId));
```

but i just returned original object without ordered.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to order your root ids by the "numeric" field of the child ids matching "mySendendId"?

Comment: Also, a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: mySendedId is the value of the values.ID , if mySendedId and values.ID is equal then order by using values.numeric to order someObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should do what you are looking for:

```
orderedObject= someObject.OrderBy(a => a.Values.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == mySenedId)?.numeric ?? int.MaxValue);
```

As there is no sample to try it out I hope I theorycrafted it correctly.

It should follow this logic:

- From each object `a` in `someObject` get the `Values` and find the value `b` with the matching Id
- If there is more than one match, throw an exception (this is what the `SingleOrDefault` does compared to `FirstOrDefault`)
- If there is no value matching the Id, SingleOrDefault will return null - thus the null coalesce will select int.MaxValue - this means values with no match - or `numeric` being null - will be sorted to the end
- If there is a value matching the Id, select the `numeric` field from the matching child `b`.
- Order by the selected values